# How to prevent child element to move when parent dropdown?

Tags: theming

I have a `div` with `height:20px` with hover. When you put the cursor on it, a menu bar appears, this menu bar have `height:50px`.

After that i have a second `div` which is juste a yellow pannel with `margin-top: 50px` (so it's 50px from the parent who is the first div (that has : height : 20px)).

Now when the hover effect happend, the second div (the yellow pannel) moves down with the droping down effect.

How to make the second div do not have a margin top with the direct first div (his parent) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css you need to give your menu bar div an absolute position.

For Example: `.menubar { position: absolute; }` so that it overlays everything, so it won't affect anything else.

Then adjusted if needed

Example: `.menubar { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 20px; }`

Also you will need to increase the yellow div from 50px to 70px

`.yellow { margin-top: 70px; }`

Comment: This is exactly what i just made before you answer me thank you verry much it's the correct answer